# Select and parseint of a class in parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parseint

im creating a blog post where onclick 'like' it finds the class for the number of likes and adds plus one to it. i think i can do this with parse int.. can anyone help me with this >

That is the HTML

```
<span class="button_class"><a class="lik_right_stat_like" href="javascript:;">4255&nbsp;Likes&nbsp;&middot;</a></span>
```

This is the javascript.. onclick like works fine.. having trouble parsing the value for the above class and adding one to it. This is the jquery

```
$(this).parent("div").find(".lik_right_stat_like").attr("alt", count) parseint()++;
```

(im quite new to jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.button_class').click(function () {
    $(this).parent("div").find(".lik_right_stat_like").text(function (idx, text) {
        return $.trim(text).replace(/^(\d+)/, function (str) {
            return (parseInt(text.match(/^(\d+)/), 10) || 0) + 1;
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/usUbu/)